# Dynamically add selected attribute within ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

How do I dynamically make options selected using ng-repeat in a select element?

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve and the results I've gotten with my approach.

https://plnkr.co/edit/xOkNzalcw1DlJ7PU?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview

HTML

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.options = [
    {
      value: 'red',
      selected: false,
    },
    {
      value: 'blue',
      selected: true,
    },
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      data-require="angular.js@1.0.x"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<h3>Via ng-repeat</h3>

    <select multiple="yes">
      <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{option.value}}" selected="{{option.selected}}">
        {{option.value}} - option.selected = {{option.selected}} 
      </option>
    </select>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<h3>Manual</h3>
 
    <select multiple="yes">
      <option value="red">red</option>
      <option value="blue" selected>blue</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you want to select from the later drop down and want the former to get selected accordingly if I am phrasing this correctly?

Comment: Oh no, I did not include enough detail.  I'm using $scope.options for the ng-repeat section and just trying to figure out the syntax to make blue show selected when this loads, since the selected property is true.  I am trying to do this by using `selected="{{option.selected}}"` which is false for red, and true for blue.  But when this loads, both of them are selected in the ng-repeat.  The manual is an example of what I would expect the ng-repeat to look like once I've figured out the syntax (only blue is selected).  Thank you for responding!

Comment: I suggest you checkout this useful library https://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main. It can easily show preselected values based on the object properties in the array. 
What you're trying to achieve can get a bit cumbersome without using ng-options and ng-model